# Can't connect PI through wifi but ethernet routing is working

Tags: pi-2, wifi, ssh, ethernet

I want to access my RPI using SSH, so connected my PI to wifi router via ethernet and i'm trying to access this via Laptop connected through wifi on the same router. When I search for IP using ipscanner my RPI is not listing, whereas when I connect my laptop through ethernet, RPI is listing in ipscanner. Please help.

Comment: Sounds like a router configuration problem.

Comment: I think we are going to need to see more of your configuration.  I'd start by posting what the output of "ifconfig" looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your wireess router settigs. If you have enabled Wireess GUEST zone on your router, then wireless clients cannot initiate a connection towards your local network.